# Changing wallpapers in python

Tags: python, gconf

I'm running a Maverick on my machine, and I'm trying to write a script to change wallpapers in python. Heres my progress so far.

```
import gconf
client = gconf.client_get_default()
current_bg = client.get_string("/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename")
client.set_string("/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename","home/tsudot/Pictures/zombie.jpg")
```

After running the script I get a blank wallpaper. It shows me a white screen.

I examined the `gcnonf.xml` file and the change has been made there.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're missing a `/` at the beginning of `home/tsudot/Pictures/zombie.jpg` so the file isn't found.  To avoid this problem happening in the future, you could perhaps change your code to keep the filename in a variable and check before trying to set the config option that that file exists with `os.path.exists(filename)`.

Comment: oh turns out I had the / in the original code. Just a typo here! :D 
but filepath had problems

Comment: no problem - I hadn't realized it was so simple to set a new background programmatically, in fact, so I like the question :)